# iphone in-app purchases not working after rejection

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, appstore-approval

I recently had an issue with my in-app purchases, so had them rejected.  I found that upon creating new ones and approving them, I am getting no products back from my SKProductsRequest.  Do new in-app purchases require some delay to be updated on their servers or is there some common reason that they stop working when an app is rejected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out my paid applications contract wasn't filled out, so the server was silently rejecting any product requests.